# How to customize google maps infowindow in rails using ym4r_gm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I integrated google maps in my rails project using ym4r_gm.

I want to customize the infowindow as in trulia.com (http://www.trulia.com/for_sale/New_York … _homes_lt/).

I went through the ym4r_gm code to include 'extinfowindow', but no use :(

I'm really struggling alot to customize the bubble/infowindow.

Can any one explain me, how can we customize the infowindow using ym4r_gm.

Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the extinfowindow.js to your HEAD (after you call GMap.head, or you can add it to the plugin's map.rb), and you need to alter the ym4r-gm.js (local) file to call openextinfowindow on click.

```
function addInfoWindowToMarker(marker,info,options){
    GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){ 
            marker.openExtInfoWindow(
            map,
            "infoWindowID",
            "info box text",
            {beakOffset: 3}
          ); 
        });
    return marker;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great help stewart. I already closed this issue by doing same thing what you have explained here. :) I overwrite addInfoWindowToMarker in local ym4r_gm.js file .